# css mouseover effect bug only in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

Currently facing a problem in with a css mouseover effect that I created.

If you have a look at this `http://176.32.230.21/luciaphotography.co.uk/` using chrome everything works fine, whenever you mouse over the any of the images, you see the relevant category image mouse over. Now in firefox, it does work but if you notice there are 2 problems:

1. the images are not being resized properly, you can see the text on the swatches look blurry.
2. (more important) if you notice that when you mouseover, the first image goes slightly smaller and you can see the category image slightly on the right of the picture (you'll see what I mean).

I'm not quite sure what's happening but the second problem does not happen in internet explorer although the first problem does. I assum it's because I'm using IE9 and not 10.

I'm using the latest versions of chrome and FF.

```
<div id="widget1" class="widget-container">         
<div class="textwidget">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="bottom" src="images/editorial.png">
        <img class="top" src="images/front1.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

```
.widget-container {
    height: 155px;
    width:155px;
    padding-right:2px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.widget-container img.top:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
.widget-container img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.bottom {
    max-width: 155px;
    max-height: 155px;
}

.top {
    max-width: 155px;
    max-height: 155px;
}
```

Comment: Both chrome and firefox have the same result for me except firefox has very slightly thinner font, so you could make it slightly bigger.

Comment: Does the original image not go a bit smaller when you mouseover it?

Comment: Oh right it seems to go 1 px smaller on the right. Set .top to max-width: 156px;max-height:156px;

Comment: Fixed it, it's actually an issue with firefox rounding the number up or down for some reason, so if I use 154px it works fine.